# smartparens strict mode insert single quote before variable

Tags: smartparens

I'm using `smartparens-global-strict-mode`and having issues quoting variables. How do I get something like `'varname`? My current strategy, which seems ridiculous, is to do:

`'|'` (sp inserts both pairs)

`'varname'` (write the varname)

at this point, I do `M-x smartparens-strict-mode`, which toggles it off, delete the right `'`, then do `M-x smartparens-strict-mode` again to turn it back on. But there's got to be a better way, right? Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 4):

Specific answer: The default configuration for smartparens should cover this, but perhaps you aren't loading the default config. Make sure that

```
(require 'smartparens-config)
```

is in your `.emacs.d` instead of just `(require 'smartparens)`.

More generally, to see the delimiters that smartparens is currently tracking, inspect variable `sp-pair-list`. You can use the functions `sp-pair` and `sp-local-pair` to configure it. For example to globally disable autoinsertion of closing single quotes you can write:

```
(sp-pair "'" "'" :actions nil)
```

Or to disable for specific modes:

```
(sp-local-pair '(emacs-lisp-mode) "'" "'" :actions nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

What major mode are you using? In `emacs-lisp-mode`, Smartparens does not automatically close single quotes.

To insert a single character, use `C-q`, `quoted-insert`, followed by the character. E.g. `C-q '` to insert a single quote.

Comment: Huh. This happens in all major modes, including `emacs-lisp-mode`. I guess something else in my init file is causing that, then...

The `C-q` tip works. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Eval `(sp-pair "'" "'" :actions :rem)` to disable any cleverness with the apostrophe. This removes the entry for `'` from sp-pairs.  You can get the right arguments to pass into `sp-pair` by evaling `(sp-get-pair "'")`.

Comment: Can you elaborate, to explain how that sexp does what you say? That could make your answer more helpful.